# display child accordion only when parent accordion is opened

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am developing an accordion which is nested in character. I mean, an accordion can have its child accordion as well. Right now, a simple accordion has been build up. The toggling part works either. However, there is a problem. Child accordion is shown without opening the parent accordion. How can i show child accordion only when parent accordion is clicked and hide it when clicked again?

Here is what i have done

```
class Accordion extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    let state = { activeSections: {} };

    React.Children.toArray(props.children).forEach(child => {
      if (child) {
        state.activeSections[child.props.name] = !!child.props.defaultOpen;
      }
    });

    this.state = state;
  }
  get isControlled() {
    return typeof this.props.onToggle === "function";
  }
  expandAll = () => {
    if (this.isControlled) {
      this.props.expandAll();
    } else {
      let { activeSections } = this.state;
      Object.keys(activeSections).forEach(k => (activeSections[k] = true));
      this.setState({ activeSections });
    }
  };
  collapseAll = () => {
    if (this.isControlled) {
      this.props.collapseAll();
    } else {
      let { activeSections } = this.state;
      Object.keys(activeSections).forEach(k => (activeSections[k] = false));
      this.setState({ activeSections });
    }
  };
  onToggle = name => {
    if (this.isControlled) {
      this.props.onToggle(name);
    } else {
      let activeSections = this.state.activeSections;
      this.setState({
        activeSections: { ...activeSections, [name]: !activeSections[name] }
      });
    }
  };
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    let { activeSections } = this.state;

    React.Children.toArray(nextProps.children)
      .filter(c => c)
      .forEach(child => {
        if (activeSections[child.props.name] == null) {
          activeSections[child.props.name] = !!child.props.defaultOpen;
        }
      });
    this.setState({ activeSections });
  }
  render() {
    let { activeSections } = this.state;
    let children = React.Children.toArray(this.props.children);

    // if (!children.find(c => c && c.type === AccordionHeader)) {
    //   children = [<AccordionHeader />, ...children];
    // }
    console.log("children", children);
    return (
      <div>
        {children.map(child => {
          if (!child) {
            return child;
          } else if (child.type === AccordionItem) {
            return React.cloneElement(child, {
              expanded: this.isControlled
                ? child.props.expanded
                : activeSections[child.props.name],
              onToggle: this.onToggle
            });
          } else {
            return child;
          }
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Accordion;





class AccordionItem extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let {
      expanded,
      caption,
      onToggle,
      name,
      children,
      render,
      ...rest
    } = this.props;
    return render ? (
      render({ onToggle: onToggle.bind(null, name), expanded })
    ) : (
      <styled.AccordionItem style={{ margin: 10 }}>
        <styled.AccordionHeader
          onClick={() => onToggle(name)}
          active={expanded}
        >
          {caption}
        </styled.AccordionHeader>
        <styled.AccordionBody active={rest.defaultOpen || expanded}>
          {children && (
            <styled.AccordionBodyContent>
              {children}
            </styled.AccordionBodyContent>
          )}
        </styled.AccordionBody>
      </styled.AccordionItem>
    );
  }
}

export default AccordionItem;
```

I have create a working example in the sandbox and here it is

https://codesandbox.io/s/z25j8q2v4m

Comment: I have seen your code and worked for me!

Comment: can you open the sub panel 1 accordion and then open panel 1 accordion and close panel 1 accordion, then only panel 1 accordion gets close. Closing panel 1 accordion does not hides sub panel 1 accordion. Like when parent folder is closed, the folder inside that parent folder is not shown.